# Proof of Well ordering principle (Analysis by Tao)

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> (From Analysis 1 by Tao) Exercise 8.1.2. Prove Proposition 8.1.4. (Hint: you can either use induction, or use the principle of infinite descent, or use the least upper bound (or greatest lower bound) principle.) Does the well-ordering principle work if we replace the natural numbers by the integers? What if we replace the natural numbers by the positive rationals? Explain.
>
> Proposition 8.1.4 (Well ordering principle). Let $X$ be a non-empty subset of the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. Then there exists exactly one element $n \in X$ such that $n \le m$ for all $m \in X$. In other words, every non-empty set of natural numbers has a minimum element.

Attempt: Use induction on the cardinality of $X$. When $|X|=1$, there is only one element, so the result easily follows. Suppose that when $|X| = n$, the result follows, and consider the case where $|X| = n+1$. Let $x \in X$. Then, $X = \{x\} \cup (X-\{x\})$. We know that $(X-\{x\})$ has a minimum element, called $y$ by the induction hypothesis. If $x < y$, then $x$ is the minimum element of $X$, otherwise $y$ is the minimum element. This closes the induction.

When $X$ is a subset of integers, then $\inf X$ can be $- \infty$ (undefined). Thus, Well ordering principle does not hold. When $X$ is a subset of the positive rationals (e.g. $\{x \in Q : x \in (0, 1)\}$), it does not hold as well.

The proposition is intuitive, but for me it is not easy to prove. I appreciate if  you check my answer and give some help.

Comment: The inductive argument only works for finite $X$.

Comment: Hint: For infinite $X$, since $X$ is non-empty there must be some $n \in X$.  Then consider $X \cap \{1,2,3, \ldots, n\}$.

Comment: The induction itself looks good to me. However I think it does not cover the case of infinite subsets (eg. all even numbers). I guess you have to give an argument, why it suffices to consider finite subsets...